# Google Drive API Authorizing with Google + Sign in

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have implemented google drive api in my website(in php) with the Oauth 2 authorizing method where different users have to enter their own client id and client secret to access files in his/her google drive.

But to make it more user friendly I am planning to implement  Google+ Sign-in method as in this url https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth.

Can anyone provide me with a tutorial on how to use google + sign in to get the refresh token for google drive api requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps ...

1. Call the auth URL with your app/client ID and the scopes you require. Include the "email" scope.
2. Google will walk the user through login the and (if the first time through) authorisation dialogues
3. Eventually the browser will redirect back to your oauthcallback url, and pass you an auth code
4. Call google to convert the auth code to a refresh token. This will also return the user's google ID and an access token.
5. Store the user ID in your session so you can identify the user subsequently
6. Persist the refresh token alongside the google user id in a database

On subsequent visits...

1. If you have the google user id in the your session, you can retrieve the refresh token from your database and use it to generate access tokens as you need them.
2. If you do NOT have the google user id in your session, go through the steps above. This time, google will NOT prompt the user for authorisation (since it's already authorised), and the refresh token will be blank (since you already have one stored).

Everything you need to know is within the oauth playground page. If you click through the buttons, you will see that it is following the steps I outlined above.

You then need to deal with the possible error situations, eg

- user declines permission
- user withdraws permission
- google expired the refresh token (happens a lot) so you need to re-auth
- timeouts

Comment: Here does each user need to create his own client id?  What I am trying is to provide an area where user can access his google drive files simply using his username and password.

Comment: Client Id refers to your application. The google documentation variously refers to it as client-id, application id,and I've seen another permutation somewhere. So the answer is no, the user does not need to create a client id.

Comment: @pinoyyid Do you have any pointer/url to step 4 "Call google to convert the auth code to a refresh token. This will also return the user's google ID and an access token."?

Comment: if you go through the steps using the Oauth Playground, you can see the calls